# cp command can't find some directories

Tags: macos, command-line, cp

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files/directories using a terminal command, cp.  The command I'm using is:

```
sudo cp -r *.tests ~/Desktop
```

tests are directories with stuff in them.  However I get a few No such file or directory errors.  I'm not sure how I can get this error if I'm doing a recursive copy. If it doesn't exist, how would I be seeing it?

Comment: Which version of Unix? Do any of the filenames have spaces in them? ( I guess that shouldn't matter, but ... ?). Good luck.

Comment: Mac OS X, some do, some don't

Answer (score 1):

If the directory you are in, or any below it, are being modified while you are doing the copy you would see that error. For example, if after you started the `cp` some other process deleted a file or directory.

Comment: I know that no other process is touching those files

Comment: Unless your drive is going bad or something similar, I'd say it's most definitely something other process deleting those files. `lsof` is your friend.

Comment: After running cp and seeing the files/directories that apparently don't exist, I run lsof and those files/directories are not in the list output by lsof

Comment: Is it how cp is traversing your directories? Some symlink sending you off into the weeds? Hard to debug this type of problem without seeing the filesystem. :-/

Answer (score 0):

From the `cp` man page (under OS X v10.6.8):

```
Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.
```

So try `cp -R` instead.  If that doesn't do it, is there anything notable about the files it gets errors on?  Do they exist?  Are they AppleDouble files (metadata pseudo-files with names starting with "._")?